# Update time only if not a minute passed

Tags: postgresql

I have created the next table.

```
-- TABLE user_time
user_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
prev_time TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT NOW(),
total_time INTERVAL DEFAULT interval '0 second'
```

**I have to add an interval value** to the `total_time`, e.g.

```
total_time = total_time + NOW() - prev_time
```

**only if** not a minute passed since prev_time (so, less than 1 minute passed) **in a single query.**

The next construction is about what I want but it's wrong:

```
UPDATE user_time SET total_time = total_time +
(
    SELECT NOW() - prev_time incinterval,
    CASE
        WHEN incinterval < interval '1 minute' THEN incinterval
        ELSE interval '0 second'
        END
    FROM user_time WHERE user_id=6
)
```

Firstly the SELECT is wrong, PostgreSQL does not recognize `incinterval` in the CASE construction. Secondly there is the first extra column in SELECT which creates a pseudo name.

Do you have an idea how to correct the query **OR** 
Is it the common practice to increment total time with the condition and store it to a database with a single query?

Answer (score 1):

You can not expect Postgres to respect your alias like this inside a SELECT. Here's the way to go:

```
UPDATE user_time SET total_time = total_time +
(
    SELECT 
      CASE
        WHEN NOW() - prev_time < interval '1 minute' 
        THEN NOW() - prev_time
        ELSE interval '0 second'
        END
    FROM user_time WHERE user_id=6
)
```

Or to use your alias:

```
UPDATE user_time SET total_time = total_time +
(
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN incinterval < interval '1 minute' 
            THEN incinterval
            ELSE interval '0 second'
            END
    FROM(
        SELECT 
            NOW() - prev_time incinterval
        FROM user_time WHERE user_id=6 
        ) foo
)
```

**Edit after comment**:
Simply add `, prev_time = NOW()` after the last parenthesis in any option you choose from those above.

Comment: To make all system working we should also update prev_time=NOW() in the query.

Comment: Add the second column with value you'd like to update it to after the last parenthesis in this statement. I've edited my answer.

Comment: And WHERE user_id=6 for UPDATE.

Comment: There can be a problem, excuse me. If we make several queries in short time then the table user_time is dead-locked. So, the solution may be impractical. I think, I have the wrong question.

Comment: You didn't say anything about the context. You just asked for "an idea how to correct the query".

Comment: Yeah, but the solution is unusable. I can't mark it as a correct answer. But thank you, it's an idea.

Comment: If I approve it people try to use it. And they will have locking problems, and then they'll be dissapointed.

Comment: Could you please explain to me what is the real problem? Columns being updated with value now() from start of the update query?

Comment: I didn't mean 'use my query'. I did: what the practice to solve the problem (or a momentary idea)? But, of course, only working ideas are approved.

Comment: Excuse me, I have clarified the question.

Comment: The real problem is to save the time an user was on a site. If an user clicked at least every one minute then total time increments.

Answer (score 0):

The deadlock issue can be resolved by doing the analysis post hoc. Just log the queries and "roll up" clusters that meet your interval spec. This allows for variable-length intervals, which can be very useful for sites that provide dense content.

The "post hoc" process can/should run periodically in overlapping ranges to catch longer intervals.

There is an relevant example of a generalizable temporal clustering query using analytic functions from about 8 years ago on asktom.oracle.com.